# how to create sitemap in laravel website to help google found my website

Tags: laravel-8

I need sitemap file to be read data form DB , For  example say we have website and  google searchers  found content  title and body , and show all website  links .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use spatie laravel/sitemap pacakge: https://github.com/spatie/laravel-sitemap

It is easy to install and implement just follow the steps in the readme.